# about navigation controller in view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In the appdelagate, we have a UINavigationController and the view controllers as well. then in it we can initialize the navigation controller with the root view controller. And I understand why need them too.

However, in the sample code of my reference book(iPhone SDK Application Development, author: Jonathan Zdziarski), all view controller classes were added with a navigation controller as property, while they seem to be never used. So what is the meaning of having them as property in view controller classes?

e.g

```
@interface XYZViewController: UIViewController
{
  UITextView *textView;
  UIButton *button;
  .....
  .....
  UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

-(void)...

.....
...
@end
```

One more question:

All UIViewController instances can have the property "navigationItem" once they are navigated. so what do this navigationItem refer to? does it refer to the navigation controller that is navigating the view controller?

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController` has `navigationController` property that is handled by the framework and it points to the parent `UINavigationController` if the view controller in question has one.

Check the documentation for more info:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The same documentation will tell you that `navigationItem` is a `UINavigationItem` object that represents a view controller in the navigation bar. You can customise its appearance, like title, prompt, back button behaviour, etc.

That said, I have no idea why your book adds a `navigationController` property to `UIViewController` subclasses. It was added in iOS 2.0, a long time ago already... Anyway, you shouldn't need to add it, as it's provided in `UIViewController` class.